# SQL Server database will not be created with EF Core 8 in docker-compose mode

Tags: asp.net, docker, entity-framework, docker-compose

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  demonetwork:

services:
  demoappdb:
    container_name: app-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - 8002:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=password@12345#
    networks:
      - demonetwork
  lightcleanarchitecturewebapi:
    container_name: lca-app
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}lightcleanarchitecturewebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - demoappdb
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=demoappdb
      - DB_NAME=DemoBlazorApp
      - DB_SA_PASSWORD=password@12345#
    networks:
      - demonetwork
```

When I want to run my migration to create a database I get this error:

> 2024-01-12 16:28:38 Cannot load library libgssapi_krb5.so.2
>
> 2024-01-12 16:28:38 Error: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

Error happened on context.Database.Migrate():

```
 using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
 {
     var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
     context.Database.Migrate();        
 }
```

This is my Docker file:

```
# Use a Debian-based image with ASP.NET runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Web/LightCleanArchitecture.WebApi.csproj", "src/Web/"]
COPY ["src/Application/LightCleanArchitecture.Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/LightCleanArchitecture.Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/LightCleanArchitecture.Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./src/Web/./LightCleanArchitecture.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "./LightCleanArchitecture.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./LightCleanArchitecture.WebApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .    
  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LightCleanArchitecture.WebApi.dll"]
```

This problem only happens on ASP.NET Core 8, it's working properly for .NET 6.

I think I have to install `libgssapi_krb5.so.2` on the docker image that I created, but I could not find how to do it.

If you have any experiences in this case, please share it.

Comment: Can you include the contents of your dockerfile for your web api?

Comment: absolutely Yes, the question was edited and the dockerfile added to it

Comment: Do you have a [mre] you can post somewhere?

Comment: Also how are you trying to run migration?

Comment: let me push my changes to my GitHub repository

Comment: this is code repository, please check feature/dockerize branch
https://github.com/Sabermotamedi/LightCleanArchitecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I understand, this error caused my program to crash,
but I could not get any exception error in the catch part.

> 2024-01-12 16:28:38 Cannot load library libgssapi_krb5.so.2
>
> 2024-01-12 16:28:38 Error: libgssapi_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared
> Object file: No such file or directory

what did I do? I changed my base image from **aspnet:8.0** to **aspnet:8.0-jammy-amd64**, After this change, I could get an error message in the catch part.

That error was about my connection string, I had to add this option **"Trusted_Connection = false"** to fix this issue.

Comment: Setting "Trusted_Connection = false" in my connection string fixed the same issue for me

Comment: This is a breaking change in the docker containers for .net 8.0. A list of changes can be found in this blog: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-updates-to-docker-images-in-dotnet-8/